# How to find a date or range of dates that don't exist in another range of dates

Tags: excel

I've got a list of colleges and when their respective spring break dates are and I'm trying to find the longest range of dates within the month of March when there are no schools (or the fewest) on their break.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is a small sample size of my data (I don't know how to format into a table)

```
School                                          State   Spring Break Dates
Abraham Baldwin Agricultural College              GA    03/17/2018 to 03/25/2018
Adams State College                               CO    03/24/2018 to 04/01/2018
Adelphi University                                NY    03/10/2018 to 03/18/2018
Adrian College                                    MI    02/24/2018 to 03/04/2018
Aims Community College - Greeley                  CO    03/10/2018 to 03/18/2018
Alabama Agricultural and Mechanical University    AL    03/24/2018 to 04/01/2018
Alabama State University                          AL    03/17/2018 to 03/25/2018
Alamance Community College                        NC    03/10/2018 to 03/18/2018
Albany College of Pharmacy and Health Sciences    NY    03/10/2018 to 03/18/2018
Albany State University                           GA    03/10/2018 to 03/18/2018
Albright College                                  PA    03/10/2018 to 03/18/2018
Alfred University                                 NY    03/03/2018 to 03/11/2018
Allegheny College                                 PA    03/17/2018 to 03/25/2018
Allen University                                  SC    03/17/2018 to 03/25/2018
American International College                    MA    03/10/2018 to 03/18/2018
American University                               DC    03/03/2018 to 03/11/2018
```

Comment: Please update your Question with a small sample of your data.

Comment: How do you want to see the ouput?  Longest without depends on the dates you want to test.  Currently you could say the longest is after 4/1 and before the spring breaks start in 2019.  So longest is relative to a window you set.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah I thought that, I should have put it in the post. So ideally I would like to see within the month of March.

Comment: Suppose that (a) there was a single day where every school except one was not on break, and (b) there is a 2-day period where 75% of all schools are not on break. What wins in your logic? As it stands I don't think there is a definitive answer to the question you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

So here's one way to do it...

As I understand it, you're looking to determine the overlap (or not) of the spring breaks of the various colleges during the month of March. So I set up your test data in this manner:

[image]

Then, in columns to the right, I established an area that marks one column for each day in the month of March. Within each of the cells, I used the following formula (relative-copied to each cell):

```
=IF(AND(G$1>=$C2,G$1<=$E2),1,0)
```

and of course ran a `SUM` for each column.

The results of that are:

[image]

So the totals row now shows the overall overlap between the various spring breaks.

I'm not entirely clear if this is your intended result, but it's at least one way to visualizing and summing up the data.

> **EDIT: Add Conditional Highlighting**
>   Here's a bonus for fun... conditionally highlight those columns (spring breaks) whose sums are in the lowest 25% of the date range.

For this,

1. Highlight the entire set of columns `G:AJ`
2. Select `Conditional Format-->Manage Rules...`, then click `New Rule`
3. Now choose `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
4. In the input area enter `=PERCENTRANK.INC($G$18:$AJ$18,G$18)<0.25`
5. Choose some fill color from the `Format...` button
6. Click `OK`, then `Apply` and look at your data area

[image]

Comment: Hey @PeterT that's actually a good idea - I can spread days across that range and just sum up the totals and basically pick the lowest score. The one with the lowest score should theoretically be the days that have the least amount of colleges taking those days for SB. Nice one!

Comment: I had to run out earlier, and didn't have time to post the conditional formatting part, see above edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just another idea, one that avoids the need for all the helper columns:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E2>=--LEFT($C$2:$C$17,10))*(E2<=--RIGHT($C$2:$C$17,10)))
```

[image]